# Is there a way to set up the text colour chancing with every new sentence in Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs

I'd really like to have a different colour with every new line of text. I spend time selecting each line and changing the colour that way. 
Is there a macro that would do that automatically for me?

Comment: How should the colors be selected?

Answer (score -3):

Macros is not supported by Google docs. The best thing Google have done with a similar tool is Appscript that allows you to add custom menus, dialogs and side bars across all Google desk apps (docs,sheets,forms).  FYI: not related to question  
[Quickstart: Macros, Menus, and Custom Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/macros)